# Power BI : implementing column chart with grouped status label?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I want to implement the graph with status label on various transaction status. I have added the reference graph below.
[transaction status graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqsFe.jpg)

In the above graph, **x-transaction status** , **y-transaction count**, transaction status are completed, InProgress, start, wait, stopped, failed.

If the status are wait, InProgress, start then it should comes under "ongoing" category.
If status is stopped , failed it should be grouped and comes under interrupted category.

I have grouped the transaction status and created the new column, but am unable to get exact grouping design as mentioned in the image.